# dom4j - xpath - get xml as string for Document.valueOf

Tags: java, xpath, dom4j

Is there a way to write XPath expression that will be returning xml tree as string when called with `Document.valueOf` method from dom4j library? I tried `/node()`, but it returns just texts in all nodes, not including tags.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1 :**

```
String result = document.toXML().toString();
```

**Method 2 :** (a more elegant aproach)

```
DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(document);

StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
StreamResult streamResult = new StreamResult(writer);

TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory .newTransformer();
transformer.transform(domSource, streamResult);
String result = writer.toString();
```

Comment: I need XPath expression, not the Java code. Unfortunately I already have a code that use `Documend.valueOf` method and I can't change it